# Notation for collection of ordered $k$-sets with distinct elements?

Tags: combinatorics

For a set $A$ and a positive integer $k$, typical we write $A^k$ as the notation for
$$\{(a_1,\dots,a_k): a_i\in A\text{ for }i=1,\dots,k\}.$$
For example, it is common to see $\mathbb{Z}^k, \mathbb{R}^k$ and so on.

I am wondering if there is any common notation, especially in combinatorics, for the collection of ordered $k$-sets with distinct elements from $A$, say
$$\{(a_1,\dots, a_k)\in A^k: a_i\neq a_j \text{ for any }i\neq j  \}?$$
Any reference?

Comment: That is the set of partial permutatons of length $k$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_permutation . I don't know whether it has a standard name or notation. Feel free to invent one if necessary.